# Powermock and Mockito with RETURN_DEEP_STUBS and a fluent interface (Jsoup)

Tags: java, jsoup, mockito, powermock

I'm using Mockito 1.9.5 and Powermock 1.5.2

This is my test code

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Jsoup.class)
public class PowerMockTest {    
    @Test
    public void test1() throws IOException {
        mockStatic(Jsoup.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

        Jsoup.connect("foo");
    }
}
```

When I run it I get an exception. It looks like Powermock is handing over the reigns to Mockito when it tries to return the answer, and Mockito isn't handling it correctly (I'm sure this has something to do with the static mock).

Does anyone know a good "Answer" implementation that will do the same thing as RETURN_DEEP_STUBS with a static class like Jsoup that returns itself?

If I stub out each individual call to Jsoup's static methods then I can get it to work, but I'd rather not have to do that.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.defaultanswers.ReturnsDeepStubs.getMock(ReturnsDeepStubs.java:47)
    at org.mockito.internal.stubbing.defaultanswers.ReturnsDeepStubs.answer(ReturnsDeepStubs.java:39)
    at org.mockito.internal.handler.MockHandlerImpl.handle(MockHandlerImpl.java:93)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocation.MockitoMethodInvocationControl.performIntercept(MockitoMethodInvocationControl.java:260)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.invocation.MockitoMethodInvocationControl.invoke(MockitoMethodInvocationControl.java:192)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:105)
    at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.methodCall(MockGateway.java:60)
    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java)
    at CommissionChecker.PowerMockTest.test1(PowerMockTest.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:202)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Comment: It seems that powermock does not support RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=487

Comment: Why do you want to test ? May be you can just use the default answer

Comment: I was trying to use RETURN_DEEP_STUBS with a large number of static methods (which is all JSoup offers). Looks like the answer is that it doesn't support that. If you want to give that answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This issue](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=487) indicates thats powermock does not support [`Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS):

> PowerMock has never supported deep stub calls

Comment: My solution to this was to wrap the JSoup library in an instantiable class that delegates to the static methods. I could then create a mock copy of the instantiable delegate class, instead of trying to mock JSoup directly.